# Regex: match many words multiple times

Tags: regex

I need a regex that matches words and combinations of words, but, I don't know what will be next to those words. I need to match fruits apple,bbanana and orange. fruits will be separated by spaces.

```
"sometext apple bananamoretext"
//Should match "apple banana"

"sometext appledifferentmoretext"
//Should match "apple"

"sometext bananaadditionaltext"
//Should match "banana"

"sometext apple orangesomethingelse"
//Should match "apple orange"
```

What I have is this:

```
 /sometext\s((apple|banana|orange)(\s+))*/
```

But I only get `apple` can't get other fruits

Comment: What is your regex flavor?

Comment: You are adding `\s+` after matched word. `banana` and `orange` are not followed by whitespaces. That's why they are not matching.

Comment: @Rahul whitespaces might be between fruits (if more fruits are present). I need to match all fruits in the sentence

Comment: @anubhava I'm using ruby

Comment: Indeed. But in your given strings whitespaces are not present after orange and banana. That's why your regex is failing to match them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex for your matches:

```
(?:apple|banana|orange)(?:\s+(?:apple|banana|orange))*
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/P0IQou/1)

[Ruby RegEx Demo](http://rubular.com/r/RleYWgT7w4)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `(?:apple|banana|orange)`: Match one of the given fruit names
- `(?:`: Start a non-capturing group

  - `\s+`: Match 1 or more of whitespaces
  - `(?:apple|banana|orange)`: Match one of the given fruit names
- `)*`: End non-capturing group. Match 0 or more of these groups

Comment: This works, but could you explain me what was missing?

Comment: I have added explanation in my answer.